# WebView в reactNative для веб версии

Tags: react-native

Подключил пакет  react-native-webview. Для android он прекрасно работает. А на веб версии падает ошибка:

React Native WebView does not support this platform.

Затем пытаюсь в коде написать условие зависимости от платформы

```
if (Platform.OS === 'web')
    return <iframe src={this.props.url}/>

return <WebView source={{ uri: this.props.url }} />
```

Но ошибка выше всё равно падает.
Кто-нибудь решал подобную проблему?